# Upload file to web using selinum

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

While uploading file to web this code should uploaded file but website getting closed

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//input[@id='userfile']")
);

elem.sendKeys("D://21.pdf");`
```

Comment: what's the comment above for?

Comment: Can you add the full exception.  And how are you creating `driver`?

Comment: What browser your using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(
By.xpath("//input[@id='userfile']")
);

elem.sendKeys("D:\\21.pdf");`
```

If your id is unqiue (as it should be) then you can do this:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("userfile"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily in any of following way :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("userfile")).sendKeys("D:\\21.pdf");
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userfile']")).sendKeys("D:\\21.pdf");
```

Make sure that your 21.pdf file is available at given path.